# Python - Comparing two text file and output differences using loops

Tags: python, file, text, while-loop, difference

**The first file:**
This is text./n abc/n 123

**The second file:**
This is text./n xyz/n 123

I'm doing an assignment that is asking me to print("No") while also printing the part of the line that is different in both the first and second file if the file is different. They are asking me to use loops to compare and find the difference than to print the differences and break the loop if the differences are found. I can't seem to get to the second line of text to make my condition true.

````
secondFile = input("Enter the second file name: ")
first = open(firstFile, 'r')
second = open(secondFile, 'r')
if first.read() == second.read():
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
    while True:
        firstLine = first.readline()
        secondLine = second.readline()
        if firstLine == secondLine:
            print(first.readline())
            print(second.readline())
            break```
````

Comment: In your code, you are breaking out of the loop when `firstline==secondline`. Make it `if firstline!=secondline`.

Comment: You've put `This is text./n abc/n 123`. If you want those to be newlines they should be `\n`

Answer (score 1):

`second.read()` consimes all the data from the file, so once you reach `first.readline()` you get only empty strings. Read the file line by line and print "Yes" only if all the lines where already compare using `for else`. You should also close the files once done, you can do it by using `with`

```
with open(firstFile, 'r') as file1, open(secondFile, 'r') as file2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
        if line1 != line2:
            print('No', line1, line2, sep='\n')
            break
    else:
        print('Yes')
```